# Is using ColdFusion 8 CFIMAGE to generate captcha still a good idea?

Tags: coldfusion, captcha, coldfusion-8

We are using ColdFusion 8.

I am working on a project that is using CFIMAGE to generate a captcha. The default level was being used and much spam was getting through.

The more difficult levels seem to be too difficult for a human to easily get, so I am apprehensive to advise increasing the difficulty.

My question is whether ColdFusion 8 CFIMAGE captcha has been totally figured out by bots and is almost worthless?

Would a custom solution be more effective than any commercially available solution?

Comment: I switched to using http://www.google.com/recaptcha and couldn't be happier.

Comment: I second @Busches' mention of recaptcha.  That's the only one I would consider using these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a cfimage problem. Many captcha's out there have been "figured out" by agents and bots and the latest trend is to simply pay some poor guy in a third world country to find fill out forms and navigate captchas.

Also remember that it's not just difficulty but pixel size, font, font size etc that make deciphering images hard for automation. Fooling with some of these options might help. Good luck.